# GCM sometimes work sometime doesn't in same device?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I create chat app in android using gcm. everything work well send and receive message from emulator and device till i get problem.

the problem is I've try in 2 device,first device samsung galaxy gio,and second device galaxy ace..

**first day** I tried send successfully message from ace to gio and receive the message,but from gio to ace i get nothing.

**second day** I get strange problem with my gcm again, I send successfully message from gio to Ace and receive the message,but from Ace to gio i get nothing.. the problem second day is **opposite** of first day, why I get problem like this?in result of gcm show success sent message but in device nothing message received.how i can solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: Have you made sure to update the device token in the server side? GCM documentation states it can change from time to time.

Comment: no. if you have link about update latest information about GCM (like my case above).please show me.I newbie in android and GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this inconsistent behavior I assume your problem is updating the registration ID's. The GCM server sometimes invalidate a registration ID and you must update it from the device. And here's how:

> When an application is updated, it should invalidate its existing
>   registration ID, as it is not guaranteed to work with the new version.
>   Because there is no lifecycle method called when the application is
>   updated, the best way to achieve this validation is by storing the
>   current application version when a registration ID is stored. Then
>   when the application is started, compare the stored value with the
>   current application version. If they do not match, invalidate the
>   stored data and start the registration process again.

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#reg-state

About how to implement the client: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Server side: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Note that if you do not have a third-party server, and your application is communicating "peer to peer" with other Android devices, you should sync this data between them.